# Shareholder options if company redomiciles

Tags: united-kingdom, canada

What happens to my shares if the dual listed company re domiciles from TSX.V to LSE only?

Bcn is the co.

Wondering how or if my shares are exchanged?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for your broker-dealer.  If the firm trades on both, then they shouldn't have an issue.  If they don't then you may have difficulties.  Check with your broker what will happen.